# Topological Sort, constrained by node's 'value'?

Tags: algorithm, graph

If I have a Directed Acyclic Graph, whose vertices represent tasks, and whose edge represents dependency, and each vertix may contain a 'value' that is in 24hr time format: (eg: 1600, 1700, 1130), this value represents the earliest time in the day this task can start.

For example:

```
Task C depends on Task B1's completion

Task C also depends on Task B2' completion

Task B1 depends on A's completion

Task B2 depends on A's completion, B2 also has a value of 1600(4pm), which means it can only start at or after 1600

Task A depends on nothing, A also has a value of 1500 (3pm), which means it can only start at or after 1500.
```

This would be a graph with 4 vertices (tasks): A, B1, B2, C. Job B1 or B2 can only run if A is completed, and job C can only run if BOTH B1 and B2 are complete.

Given this graph, how can I output a correct ordering of task complete sequence that is time-optimized. eg: in this case, both of these are correct job sequences:

```
A->B1->B2->C
A->B2->B1->C
```

But sequence 1 is more time-optimized, because in sequence 2, we have to wait till 1600 to run B2, holding everything else up. While in sequence 1, we can run B1 first, then wait till 1600. While the total completion time may not be different, optimized means "running each job as early as possible". Also for the sake of simplicity, let's not consider job duration: assume each job completes instantaneously after it runs.

So the question is, what is a sensible algorithm to use to output such a time-optimized sequence? I know that without considering time-optimizing, this is just a topological sort, but how do I enhance that algorithm to achieve time-optimization?

Comment: This is called of a "scheduling problem with time and order constraints." Scheduling is a huge topic with thousands of papers in the archival literature. Most variations are NP complete. I'm pretty sure this one (DAG ordering plus fixed no earlier than times) is, too. The usual "reasonable" approach is greedy. In this case, while building the topo sort order last first, pick the node with latest "no earlier than" time.

Comment: @Gene seems to me the greedy is optimal for this case, can you think of an example where it would fail?

Comment: Sure. If you have one task with a start constraint plus a collection of other unconstrained task, and the graph has no edges so there are no order constraints, then minimizing a schedule length can be set up as a 0/1 knapsack problem, which is weakly NP complete.

Comment: @Gene thank you for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit on 'while building the topo sort order last first, pick the node with latest 'no earlier than' ? What does 'last first' mean here ?